# what happens to a scheduled event when the server is off

Tags: mysql, events, server

A scheduled event to `00:00 AM` but at this moment server is off, what happen:

1. Event is canceled
2. Event run when server start

Comment: the event won't run

Comment: If MYSQL is not running then the bit that runs events is not running so nothing will run